# Factory reset upon unlocking

Tags: lock-screens, factory-reset, formatting

For security reasons, I want to be able to specify two lock passwords (or patterns) as follows :

One for normal unlocking the device.

Another one if entered, the device will factory reset itself (and maybe format the SD)

I want this to happen from the main Android lock screen, but with two passwords.

Comment: Interesting request.  This would require a device administrator, as normal applications do not have this access.  Personally, I don't know of any apps that have this support...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any application that does what you request. Maybe "[After Unlock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.webworks.android.apponunlock)" has a feature like that.

What I would do is make an Android application that is fired after unlocking the phone. The application would request a new password and if it is entered correctly do the factory reset and format the SD if needed.

Check this project for an example of how this could be done: [myLock](https://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/)

Answer (score 0):

Its possible with device admin & setting password policy. Im not sure I can post some sample code here or not as this site not for codes , for ex

```
mDevicePolicyManager.setMaximumFailedPasswordsForWipe(mCameraAdminReceiver, 2);
```

Comment: @MIH1406 If you want more help regarding code I can help you out.

Comment: This site is intended for end-user questions, so I would guess that the OP was not looking for code.

Answer (score -2):

Well, personally I don't think that there is any application that can help you in putting the lock over your device when wrong password is entered your device gets factory reset. But yes I have seen that function available over the HTC one M8, if you put the password over the HTC M8 wrong for 5 times it gives you the warning and if you put the password wrong for 10 times then the device automatically factory reset your device. I would say it's not possible to till data but I think if you are hungry for the function like, you can either try creating and application which can do so (but I think that would be whole tough mess) or try getting an HTC one M8.

Answer (score -3):

You might need to root your phone and find a way to add another password. You might need programming knowledge for this.

Comment: Down voted simply because it is entirely obvious. If you gave sample code or linked to a successful example, the answer would be have been up voted instead.